# show progress dialog while waiting for receiving SMS

Tags: android, sms, progressdialog

I would like to write an app to show a progress dialog while waiting to receive a SMS. When receiving SMS,  the non-null TextView smsReceive is served as the condition to dismiss progress dialog. But it gets runtimeException. Could you show me what to change in the code.

```
package cx.opseng.PerfTOLD;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sms extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static TextView smsReceive;
static TextView smsReceiveChar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sms);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String reg = i.getStringExtra("reg");
    String port = i.getStringExtra("port");

    String smsMessage = reg + port ;

    // Show SMS sent message on screen 
    TextView smsSend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsSend);
    smsSend.setText(smsMessage);
    Log.i("smsSend",String.valueOf(smsSend.getText()));
    // Send SMS message
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String number = "5556";
    sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, smsMessage, null, null);

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Sms.this);
    dialog.setMessage("working hard......");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

    // Receive SMS message
    smsReceive = null;
    smsReceive = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsReceive);
    Log.i("smsReceive",smsReceive.getText().toString());
    if (smsReceive.getText().toString() != null) {
        Log.i("smsReceive",smsReceive.getText().toString());
        String smsChar = smsReceive.getText().toString();
        Integer smsChar2 = smsChar.length();
        String smsChar3 = Integer.toString(smsChar2);
        Log.i("smsReceive2",smsChar3);
        smsReceiveChar.setText(smsChar);
        smsReceiveChar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smsReceiveChar);
    }

    if (smsReceiveChar.getText().toString() .equals("Message")) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
public static void updateMessageBox(String msg)
{
    smsReceive.append(msg);
    smsReceiveChar.append(msg);
}
```

}

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

    Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];

    for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
        sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    for(SmsMessage msg:sms){
        String num = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
        Log.i("SMS sender",num);
        if (num.equals("15555215556")) {
        Sms.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: " + msg.getOriginatingAddress() + 
                "\n" + "Message: " + msg.getMessageBody() + "\n");              }
    }
}
}
```

The logcat is as follows:

```
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cx.opseng.PerfTOLD/cx.opseng.PerfTOLD.Sms}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1579)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at cx.opseng.PerfTOLD.Sms.onCreate(Sms.java:88)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-14 11:16:56.152: E/AndroidRuntime(2091):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example which works for me.

I had issues with the progress dialog not working which was caused by my use of threading.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest package="com.mw.stackoverflow.example02"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>



    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.mw.stackoverflow.example02;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SmsUpdater
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SmsReceiver mSmsReceiver;

    private class ExaminMessagesTask extends AsyncTask<SmsMessage, Void, Boolean> 
    {
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Receiving SMS.");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

            mProgressDialog.show();
        }


        protected Boolean doInBackground(SmsMessage... messages) 
        {
            if (messages.length > 0)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Showing progress dialog.");

            }

            for (SmsMessage m: messages)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message received");
            }   

            int count = 0;
            for(SmsMessage msg:messages)
            {
                String num = msg.getOriginatingAddress();
                Log.d(TAG, num);

                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Processing message " + (count++));

                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }    
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
        {

        }   

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
        {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSmsReceiver = new SmsReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mSmsReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void gotSms(final SmsMessage[] m) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceive, number of messages: " + m.length);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new ExaminMessagesTask().execute(m);
            }   
        });
    }

}
```

`SmsReceiver.java`:

```
package com.mw.stackoverflow.example02;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "SMSREC";

    private SmsUpdater mSmsUpdater;

    public SmsReceiver(SmsUpdater u)
    {
        super();
        mSmsUpdater = u;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnReceive called.");

        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++)
        {
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        mSmsUpdater.gotSms(sms);
    }
}
```

`SmsUpdater.java`

```
package com.mw.stackoverflow.example02;

import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public interface SmsUpdater 
{
    void gotSms(SmsMessage[] m);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. My progress dialog just not working, either dismiss the dialog from the beginning or never stop. Receiving SMS is fine. Could you show me how to make the progress dialog works? I am a beginner of Android and Java.

Comment: Then update your code with something more complete and I will attempt to make it work. :)

Comment: I updated my example. Sorry for my lateness, but I was busy. :)

Comment: Thanks wojci, for taking extra time while busy, I will try it out and tell you the result.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`Hi wojci, May I ask: can this compile standalone? I always get error in:@Override
    public void gotSms(final SmsMessage[] m)

Comment: It compiles as it was taken from an eclipse project that I made.

Comment: Hi wojci,
The comments are:
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method gotSms(SmsMessage[]) of type MainActivity must override a superclass 
  method
 - implements com.mw.stackoverflow.example02.SmsUpdater.gotSms

Comment: Hi wojci, sorry I can't unzip your link.

Comment: I'm using winzip to unzip. but it said "invalid archive directory"

Comment: Rename the file to .tar.gz and try again.

Comment: Did you make it work and was it helpful towards resolving your problem?

Comment: wojci, sorry I still haven't tried that out. Thanks for your help. I will post the result once I have tried it.

Comment: wojci, thanks many many thanks. I finally able to unzip. The progress dialog indeed working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `onCreate()` of Activity  `cx.opseng.PerfTOLD.Sms` at line 85 for an reference that can be null. That is that the log says:

```
09:41:09.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 08-14 09:41:09.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1832): at cx.opseng.PerfTOLD.Sms.onCreate(Sms.java:85) 08-14
```

Since you did not post the code for it, I can't tell you which object is null.

Comment: Andre, line 85 is "public static void updateMessageBox(String msg)", what should I do to make progressdialog working?

Comment: Doesn't look so because the log says onCreate explicity. Anyway I looked in the code above and there something weird. You do `smsReceive = null;` and the next line is `String smsChar = smsReceive.getText().toString();` , id est, you set the reference to null than you try to use. This will certainly generate a NullPointerException.

Comment: I have some changes with the codes updated in the post. Got the same result. But now I know how to count in Eclipse, line 88 with this error. It is String smsChar = smsReceive.getText().toString().substring(0,6);

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that your string `smsReceive.getText().toString()` is smaller than 6 characters. You should not to extract a substring that is bigger than `String.lenght()`

Comment: Found that the String.length() is 0, not null. So I can't use .substring at all. Then how to define the condition to dismiss progress dialog?