# How to catch text message over 80 bytes in Android?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, message, mms

I am trying to make an Android app regarding text messages. I got a source code from googling and it is works fine. However, it does not work with text messages over 80 bytes or MMS. It seems that the `onReceive` method cannot catch those long text messages.

Did I miss something or make any mistakes?

Here are the permissions I added..

```
android.permission.READ_SMS, 
android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, 
android.permission.SEND_SMS, 
android.permission.WRITE_SMS, 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS, 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

This is my code:

```
public class MySMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {   
    private static String ACTIONNAME = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null  
            && ACTIONNAME.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {   
            Object[] pdu = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");  
            SmsMessage[] msg = new SmsMessage[pdu.length];   
            for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {  
                msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu[i]);  
            }   
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
            for(SmsMessage allMsg : msg) {  
                sb.append(allMsg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "&");  
                sb.append(allMsg.getDisplayMessageBody() + "&");  
                sb.append(allMsg.getTimestampMillis() + "&");  
            }  
            android.util.Log.i("SMS monitor", "data received = " + sb.toString());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code.

I implemented an [example receiver with progress dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944567/show-progress-dialog-while-waiting-for-receiving-sms) (look in the comments for compressed project) which works and can receive messages over 80b on my phone. I suggest that you look at it and compare to your code.